# The if statement goes automaticly to else statement

Tags: python

When I run the code and answer with 3, the console shows The answer is 3. This code is just an example, I worked on a code with random number.

I gave the input in the if statement, in a variable and i deleted else statement

```
answer = input("Answer of 1 + 2 = ")

if answer == 3:
    print("You're right!")
else:
    print("The answer was 3")
```

The right output would be `You're right!`

Comment: the **+** "signal plus" adding the input value and not combining it,
let's say you entered 1 and 2, what happened it parsed as string so the output is 12 not 3
so you need to use

    int (answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typecasting to the rescue!

```
answer = input("Answer of 1 + 2 = ")

if int(answer) == 3:
#  ^^^
    print("You're right!")
else:
    print("The answer was 3")
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the value you get from `input()` is of type string. If you write 3 in your console, you get

```
answer = "3"
```

and

```
"3" != 3
```

You need to cast the input to int. Add this line before the if statement:

```
answer = int(answer)
```

Be careful to check that the typed value is actually an int (you can do that by using a try catch statement, or better with a while)